# Does Python GC deal with reference-cycles like this?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, objgraph

Using [objgraph](http://mg.pov.lt/objgraph/), I found a bunch of objects like this:

[image: InstanceState loop]

Will Python's garbage collector deal with cycles like this, or will it leak?

A slightly wider view of the loop:

[image: Wider view of InstanceState loop]

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15974561/1959808

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Python's standard reference counting mechanism cannot free cycles, so the structure in your example would leak.

The [supplemental garbage collection facility](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html), however, is enabled by default and should be able to free that structure, if none of its components are reachable from the outside anymore *and they do not have `__del__()` methods*.

If they do, the garbage collector [will **not** free them](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.garbage) because it cannot determine a safe order to run these `__del__()` methods.

Comment: It should be stated explicitly that the GC you call "supplemental" is enabled by default in Python

Comment: Hurrah ! At least, peoples (you and Raymond Hettinger) who don't make confusion about GC and refs counter and who don't use "garbage collector" as synonym of "reference counting mechanism" ! I had been perplexed for a long time about the fact that I had understood things like that but I was constantly reading texts in which peoples expressed their ideas as if the GC was the responsible of the the killing of no-more-referenced objects. In your answer, the difference is perfectly expressed and clear. Thank you. Hence +1

Comment: Since it's still possible to search your way here, note that this answer is no longer correct.  `__del__` no longer prevents collection of cycles, and it does get called for cycles.

Answer (score 22):

To extend on Frédéric's answer a bit, [the "reference counts" section](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html#reference-counts) of the docs explains the supplementary cycle detection nicely.

Since I find explaining things a good way to confirm I understand it, here are some examples... With these two classes:

```
class WithDel(object):
    def __del__(self):
        print "deleting %s object at %s" % (self.__class__.__name__, id(self))


class NoDel(object):
    pass
```

Creating an object and losing the reference from `a` triggers the `__del__` method, thanks to the ref-counting:

```
>>> a = WithDel()
>>> a = None  # leaving the WithDel object with no references 
deleting WithDel object at 4299615184
```

If we make a reference loop between two objects **with no** `__del__` method, all is still leak-free, this time thanks to the cycle detection. First, enable the garbage-collection debug output:

```
>>> import gc
>>> gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_COLLECTABLE | gc.DEBUG_UNCOLLECTABLE | gc.DEBUG_OBJECTS)
```

Then make a reference loop between the two objects:

```
>>> a = NoDel(); b = NoDel()
>>> a.other = b; b.other = a  # cyclical reference
>>> a = None; b = None # Leave only the reference-cycle
>>> gc.collect()
gc: collectable <NoDel 0x10046ed50>
gc: collectable <NoDel 0x10046ed90>
gc: collectable <dict 0x100376c20>
gc: collectable <dict 0x100376b00>
4
>>> gc.garbage
[]
```

(the `dict` is from the objects internal `__dict__` attribute)

All is fine, *until* even one of the objects in the cycle contains a `__del__` method:

```
>>> a = NoDel(); b = WithDel()
>>> a.other = b; b.other = a
>>> a = None; b = None
>>> gc.collect()
gc: uncollectable <WithDel 0x10046edd0>
gc: uncollectable <dict 0x100376b00>
gc: uncollectable <NoDel 0x10046ed90>
gc: uncollectable <dict 0x100376c20>
4
>>> gc.garbage
[<__main__.WithDel object at 0x10046edd0>]
```

As Paul mentioned, the loop can be broken with a [`weakref`](http://docs.python.org/library/weakref.html):

```
>>> import weakref
>>> a = NoDel(); b = WithDel()
>>> a.other = weakref.ref(b)
>>> b.other = a # could also be a weakref
```

Then when the `b` reference to the `WithDel` object is lost, it gets deleted, despite the cycle:

```
>>> b = None
deleting WithDel object at 4299656848
>>> a.other
<weakref at 0x10045b9f0; dead>
```

Oh, [objgraph](http://mg.pov.lt/objgraph/) would have helpfully [indicated the problematic `__del__` method like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jjj7.png)

Comment: This works for me in python2, however, in python3 I'm unable to reproduce the leak... Has something changed?

Comment: @kralyk I guess this pep is responsible: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0442/

Answer (score 5):

Python's GC is designed to traverse all live objects to locate and eliminate reference cycles with no external references.

You can validate that is what is happening by running `gc.collect()` and then printing `gc.garbage` and [gc.get_objects](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html#gc.get_objects).

Answer (score 2):

If you use weakrefs for your parent pointers, then GC will happen normally.